# Mapping Rest Api Result into Object Using RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, error-handling, mapping, resttemplate

I want to consume a rest service that responds to JSON data in some structure.

I used `RestTemplate` for calling the service and I wanted to map the JSON result into java Object, this is how I am calling the service:

```
ResponseEntity<MyDto> re = RestTemplate.exchange(serviceUri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, MyDto.class);
```

The problem is, when the structure of the response is in my expectations and matches to MyDto, this code will work, but if for any reason the response has some kinds of error, for example:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "status" : 502,
    "message" : "Bad gateway."
  }
}
```

**`restTemplate.exchange`**  method will throw an exception and I will lose the server error code and message to do other business in my application.

How can I tackle this problem?

**note** : 
as the error's structure differs from the success's structure, an exception in my code is expected! But how I can manage different structures of results in specific requests from a rest Service in this case?